# Does JFrame setVisibility(false) stop all threads I created?

Tags: java

When executing the command this.setVisible(false), does it stop all threads that are running specifically on that frame?

If not, is there an easy way to stop all of them automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "all threads"? There is only one thread in a Swing program, unless you are creating more with e.g. `new Thread()` or `new SwingWorker()`.

Comment: yes, i did new Thread() and also a Thread thread = new Thread().

Comment: Well, two threads in a Swing program: the main thread (that starts the program) and the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) where all Swing operations should take place.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we have a conceptual problem here.  There are no "threads running on a JFrame."  There is one thread, [the Event Dispatch Thread,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) that runs *ALL* Swing objects, frames, etc.

The EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) does not stop because you made one window invisible.  However, if *ALL* Swing objects become unreachable (eligible for garbage collection) then the Swing EDT does shut down.  (The app-note linked below says you can also call `Window.dispose()` on a frame to make it undisplayable; it then no longer counts for keeping the EDT running.)

The more precise conditions for [shutting down the EDT are in this app-note:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/AWTThreadIssues.html)

```
 Starting with 1.4, the behavior has changed as a result of the fix for
 4030718. With the current implementation, AWT terminates all its helper
 threads allowing the application to exit cleanly when the following
 three conditions are true:

    There are no displayable AWT or Swing components.
    There are no native events in the native event queue.
    There are no AWT events in java EventQueues.
```

Prior to Java 1.4, the EDT never shuts down.  Hopefully you don't need to go that far back.

If you want to shutdown a group of threads, you have to do it manually (other than using some course method like `System.exit()`).  I would look at [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) which enable you to manage threads fairly easily.

Comment: This is what i needed, thank you. Also, i was referring to the new Thread() type threads.

Comment: Well, all threads are basically the same, but if you meant threads started with `new Thread().start()` then yes, those do NOT shut down when a window is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

No, setting the JFrame visibility to false won't stop all threads you created with `new Thread()`.

> If not, is there an easy way to stop all of them automatically?

To stop all of them automatically there is no way (unless terminate all the program)

You need to have them stored in a list or a vector, for example, and then use the method [Thread.interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--)

Something like this:

```
for(Thread thread : threads) //where threads is a List
{
    thread.interrupt();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No it does not!

The Thread does still run in background, but you cant interact with the Frame.
To Stop all threads you could do:

`System.exit(1)` which would terminate all Threads or for every  Thread
`Thread.sleep(10000000000);` which would stop the Thread for a certain amount of time (in milliseconds).